# Python API Handler - Memory usage

Tags: python, rest

I have created handler to call API Endpoints every 2 seconds in python.

Idea is, that it would be possible to call Asynch/Paralel Functions from database and so we can call more complex functions from DB without putting a strain on it or wait for it to finish.

So we created ASP.NET Asynch API, that upon call will start up respective functions.

And to fire it from DB, I created Python Function, that is running in loop to infinity and every 2 seconds will do select to single table.

In table, there are inserted rows with defined method, url, body and headers of request. Upon discovering new rows, it will fire respective functions.

Code:

```
import gc
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt
import tracemalloc
import json

import requests

class RequestHandler():*emphasized text*
    def __init__(self) -> None:           
        self.url = None
        self.body = None
        self.params = None
        self.headers = None

    def fire_post(self):

        with requests.Session() as session:
            request = session.post( self.url, headers = self.headers, params = self.params, json = self.body )
            return request
            
        
    def fire_get(self):

        with requests.Session() as session:
            request = session.get( self.url, headers = self.headers, params = self.params, json = self.body )
            return request
        
    def fire_put(self):

        with requests.Session() as session:
            request = session.put( self.url, headers = self.headers, params = self.params, json = self.body )
            return request


def get_requests(DB : db.DB_Connection):
    
    query = "select * from api.API_Handler where FiredAt is null;"
    return DB.select_query(query)
    

def fire(data, DB):

    __time = dt.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            
    __model = RequestHandler()
    __model.body = data.body_json
    __model.params = data.params_json
    __model.url = data.URL_address


    
    match data.method:
        case 'get':
            __resp = __model.fire_get()
        case 'post':
            __resp = __model.fire_post()
        case 'put':
            __resp = __model.fire_put()

    

    DB.execute(f"UPDATE api.API_Handler set FiredAt = '{__time}', Response = '{json.dumps(__resp.json())}' where API_Handler_Id = '{data.API_Handler_Id}'")

    del __time, __model, __resp  #clear memory


def main(): 
    tracemalloc.start()
    DB = db.DB_Connection()

    
    while True:
        print('Running')

        new_req = get_requests(DB)
        
        for data in new_req:

            try:
                fire(data = data, DB = DB)
            except Exception as e:
                DB.execute(f"UPDATE api.API_Handler set Response = '{e}' where API_Handler_Id = '{data.API_Handler_Id}'")
        

        
        del new_req #clear memory
        gc.collect() #unbound memory
        

        print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
        time.sleep(2)

    tracemalloc.stop()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am using tracemalloc lib to track memory usage and based on this I can see, that it goes up with time. I am using del and gc.collect to free memory, but not really succesfully.

So my question is, is this a good approach how to handle this task and what am I doing wrong while handling memory?

Comment: As a general improvement, don't create a session every time you fire a request. Call `with requests.Session() as session:` once in your main function and reuse the session by passing it to the child functions. Also doesn't tracemalloc itself grow the memory, I haven't used it before so i'm not sure?